# Can anyone recommend a good Drupal module for managing/displaying videos

Tags: files

I would like to put together a video gallery on my website and am wondering if there are any existing Drupal modules to manage that. I'm using Drupal 6 and most likely the videos will be hosted on YouTube.

Ideally, I would like to arrange them in topical albums in which each video could be annotated with a description of the videos.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. A search of drupal.org for 'video' returns 289 results, with neither emfield nor the media module in the top 10 results. The question does detail his use case, so it is feasible to come up with a recommendation.

Comment: Agreed, neither media nor emfield show up anywhere on the first page of results, even when only searching for modules. Also, this type of question is the one that has the most "on-topic" upvotes: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers/3001#3001

Comment: When there is a canonical "best module" for a use-case, having that information as a resource is invaluable to a less experienced Drupal user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal 6: [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield). Now has a D7 version too.

> This extensible module will create fields for content types that can be used to display video, image, and audio files from various third party providers. When entering the content, the user will simply paste the URL or embed code from the third party, and the module will automatically determine which content provider is being used. When displaying the content, the proper embedding format will be used.

Drupal 7: [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media)

> The Media module provides an extensible framework for managing files and multimedia assets, regardless of whether they are hosted on your own site or a 3rd party site - it is commonly referred to as a 'file browser to the internet'.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest modules to do this task are:

1. IMCE : IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal directories and quota.
2. WYSIWYG : Allows to use client-side editors to edit content.
3. CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor: loads faster (the number of files has been reduced, so the browser will perform less HTTP requests) and developers friendly.

Adding content(videos) using these modules will be simple and later css modifications can help in the positioning and look of the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a most modern approach to do this in drupal 7 is Module [Asset](http://drupal.org/project/asset). It has his its own entity Media asset to manage the medias.

It's very flexible since you can create your own types of Media Assets, which are fieldable entities, and has integration with CKEditor module.

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of CKEditor and Media module.

**CKEditor:**
It provides many HTML editing feature like:

1. Font formatting: type, size, color, style, bold, italic, etc
2. Text formatting: alignment, indentation, bullets list, etc
3. Cut and Paste, Undo and Redo
4. Link creation
5. Image insertion, with upload and server browsing support
6. Table creation and editing (add,delete rows, etc)
7. Right click context menus support
8. Complete toolbar customization
9. CSS support for a better integration in the web site
10. Lightweight and fast
11. For web developer it is easy to install and customize
12. For web users its simply easy to use!
13. Compatible with Internet Explorer 5+
14. Automatic browser detection and customization
15. Integration with ASP, ASP.NET and Javascript

**Media:** It provides an extensible framework for managing files and multimedia assets, regardless of whether they are hosted on your own site or a 3rd party site. It is a drop-in replacement for the Drupal core upload field with a unified User Interface where editors and administrators can upload, manage, and reuse files and multimedia assets.